# Wordpress get_the_author_meta display 1

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with wordpress, I have script which check author of actual page
get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );

and this work great when for example page is

mydomain.com/author/admin/ then ID of author is 1 (because admin have ID 1)

mydomain.com/author/author2/ then ID of author is 2 (because admin have ID 2)

mydomain.com/author/other-author/ then ID of author is 3 (because admin have ID 3)

but when I am on mydomain.com/blog/ which shows posts form all authors, then get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) is 1 (it should be empty or 0). So this complicate situation with my list, which is:

-All

-admin

-author2

-other-author

because when we are in All category (not specified author), then get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) says the actual author is admin, so my list of authors on page doesn't work.

Code:

```
function contributors() {
global $wpdb;

$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");
$actualauthor = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
echo $actualauthor;
echo "<li><a href=\"/blog/\"";

if ($actualauthor == '') {
    echo " style=\"font-weight:bold;\"";
}
echo ">Wszyscy</a></li>";
foreach($authors as $author) {
echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
echo $author->ID;
echo "\"";
if ($actualauthor == $author->ID) {
    echo " style=\"font-weight:bold;\"";
}
echo ">";
the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
echo " (";
echo count_user_posts($author->ID);
echo ")";
echo "</a>";
echo "</li>";
}
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: If you are imported as admin then you get 1.not specified author it means default

Comment: Please see this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/kHgVNWQ.png
I didn't choosen any author, but script bold admin, because get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) = 1, 
I just want to check the page when I am, when this is main blog page then I want bold "All authors", but get_the_author_meta work wrong.

Comment: please give me actual url.Please add code snippet in question.

Comment: http://jasnapolska.creativeheads.pl/blog/ On left side you can see "Autorzy" when you can filter authors. I just added code.

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: print_r($authors);What you get?

Comment: You created those two post from admin login

Comment: print_r($authors) display: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [user_nicename] => admin ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 2 [user_nicename] => imie_nazwisko ) )

Comment: I know I added this posts from admin login, but the clue is that, on jasnapolska.creativeheads.pl/blog/ should bold option WSZYSCY (which equals all) in authors list, because this is page which displays posts from all authors, and when I click on "admin" and goes to http://jasnapolska.creativeheads.pl/author/admin/ then author admin is correctly bolded, because I am on page with admin posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function contributors() {
    global $wpdb;

    $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");
    $actualauthor = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
    echo $actualauthor;
    echo "<li><a href=\"/blog/\"";

   //Check if on blog page
    if(!is_page( 'blog' )){
      if ($actualauthor == '') {
          echo " style=\"font-weight:bold;\"";
      }
    }
    echo ">Wszyscy</a></li>";
    foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
    echo $author->ID;
    echo "\"";
    if ($actualauthor == $author->ID) {
        echo " style=\"font-weight:bold;\"";
    }
    echo ">";
    the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
    echo " (";
    echo count_user_posts($author->ID);
    echo ")";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</li>";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@msbodetti That doesn't work, but using your advice I edited the code and now everything works, additionally when category is chosen (then the page isn't a 'blog') then author "all" is bolded. Here is code:

```
function contributors() {
global $wpdb;

$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");
$actualauthor = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
echo "<li><a href=\"/blog/\"";
if(is_page( 'blog' ) || $cat_id){
      echo " style=\"font-weight:bold;\"";
}
echo ">Wszyscy</a></li>";
foreach($authors as $author) {
echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
echo $author->ID;
echo "\"";
if ($actualauthor == $author->ID) {
    if(!is_page( 'blog' )){
        echo " style=\"font-weight:bold;\"";
    }
}
echo ">";
the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
echo " (";
echo count_user_posts($author->ID);
echo ")";
echo "</a>";
echo "</li>";
}
```

}